# Ruby on Rails Sitemap does not update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sitemap

I coded a sitemap for the first time.
Below please find my sitemap.rb file.

The problem is that I originally forgot to set the default_host to my own url. So when I download my pages sitemap file it is still www.example.com.

I changed the default host to my real domain but when I now download the sitemap, it is still showing www.example.com as the root path.

-Which means it does not update. Any idea whats wrong with the way I do it?
I also ran rake but it still does not change.

THANK YOU!

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sitemap_generator'

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.default_host = "http://www.frankfurtstartupjobs.com"

SitemapGenerator::Sitemap.create do

  Vacancy.find_each do |vacancy|
    add vacancy_path(vacancy), :lastmod => vacancy.updated_at, :priority => 0.5
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you run the rake command for regenerating the sitemap after your changes?

Comment: Can you tell me which command to use for that?

Comment: `rake sitemap:refresh`, see the docs: https://github.com/kjvarga/sitemap_generator#rake-tasks

Comment: Yes, I did try that. It does not work either. The problem is, when I run the file by the command "ruby sitemap.rb" it gives me an uninitialized constant error. Maybe thats why

Comment: That would be the problem then. Either search for these errors or update your question with more information if you need help solving these errors.

Comment: youre right, I just found out now. Thanks for the help!